# How to serialize list to XML without parent element

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` to serialize my class into a XML document.
These are my classes:

```
public class Test
{
    public List<ListItem> ListItems { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public String ID { get; set; }

    public Scenario()
    {
        this.ListItems = new List<ListItem>();
    }
}

public class ListItem
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the XML that I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Test xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ListItems>
    <ListItem>
      <Name>test1</Name>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
      <Name>test2</Name>
    </ListItem>
  </ListItems>
</Test>
```

Is it possible to get XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Test xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ListItem>
    <Name>test1</Name>
  </ListItem>
  <ListItem>
    <Name>test2</Name>
  </ListItem>
</Test>
```

Notice that in second Xml example (the one that I need to generate) `ListItem` nodes do not have parent `ListItems` node.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try

```
[XmlElement("ListItem")]
public List<ListItem> ListItems { get; set; }
```